# Bugs: New site, five minor css oddities

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

### 1.

Help centre. Very hard to read all those links on gray background:
[image]

### 2.

Missing space on personal stat page:

[image]

### 3.

Personal stat page; "accepted answer"-colour really hard to see

[image]

### 4.

Buttons in help centre looking off in comparison to each other:

[image]

### 5.

At certain zoom-stage, "ask question" falls out of its container:

[image]

Comment: Irony for a graphic design page to have so many color issues with it being hard to see some text etc.

Comment: that it is, but not as much as it points out just how hard design is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed everything except the "5", it's a normal behavior due to the zoom of the browser. The changes will be live after our next production build

Comment: Thanks! Much appreciated.

Comment: Stéphane: good work, but `2.` above still needs a touch more space, there's no space between the score and the question title if the score is in three figures. A couple of pixels of horizontal padding would fix this.

Comment: the issue 2 still persists (MBP)